# Is there a replacement for AniDisable for firefox 3.5?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, animated-gif

Anidisable is a very handy FF extension that allows to block animated gifs, but still allows to view them when you really want. Unfortunately, it hasn't been ported to FF 3.5 yet. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Type *about:config* in your address bar
2. Search for **image.animation_mode**
3. Change the value to *none*

It will show the gif first frame, but will not display the animation.

<strike>Agreed, this is less handy then using an extension allowing you to set/unset animated gifs, as was the case with AniDisable. There's a nice tutorial for creating Firefox Extensions at http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/08/how-to-create-firefox-extensions/.</strike>

**EDIT:**
I just inspected the plugin. **It is indeed compatible with Firefox 3.5**. Download it from http://www.siliconmethod.com/firefox/anidisable/ and follow these steps.

1. Rename the file extension to *zip*.
2. Open it with your favorite
   decompressor.
3. Extract the file *install.rdf*.
4. Edit the following line
   `<em:maxVersion>3.0+</em:maxVersion>`
5. Change it to
   `<em:maxVersion>3.5+</em:maxVersion>`
6. Put it back in the zip file,
   replacing the old file
7. Rename the zip extension back to
   *xpi*
8. Install by selecting *Open File...*
   from the Firefox *File* menu

AniDisable works by making changes to the above about:config setting. The changes it does to this setting (*none*, *once*, and *normal*) are still in effect as of Firefox 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

No longer works with FF 3.6. It will appear to install, but there's no contextual menu and the Preferences button within the Add-on description doesn't function either.