# Browser which supports syntax highlighting

Tags: browser, browser-addons, syntax-highlighting

Does anybody know of some browser or browser addon which supports syntax highlighting when opening a web file like

- http://gears.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gears/geolocation/wifi_data_provider_win32.cc
- http://standardpascal.org/basics.pas

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of Addon's you may wish to try:

[**CodeSnippet**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9113)
[**CodeViewer**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6855)

On both cases, because they are for older versions of the browser, if you are using version 3.5 of Firefox you will need to follow instructions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/43427/is-there-a-replacement-for-anidisable-for-firefox-3-5/43437#43437) as to install them on your newer Firefox.

Alternatively you can use:
[**Launchy**](http://gemal.dk/mozilla/launchy.html)

Essentially what you get is the ability to launch links like you provided in an external application you own capable of syntax highlighting.

Finally you can opt for online services:
[**GeSHi**](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php)

This is what I've been using lately. It is a online demonstration of GeSHi which allows you to provide source code through various means, including an url. Very complete with many features and the default settings are more than pleasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Firefox**, you may want to try the "[Userscripts.org Always Allow Syntax Highlighting](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/50256)" script for [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748) or the [CodeSnippet](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9113) addon which both advertise the feature you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Konqueror

Hey, you asked. ;-)